# Getting probability as 0 or 1 in KNN (predict_proba)

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I was using KNN from sklearn and predicted the labels using predict_proba. I was expecting the values in the range of 0 to 1 since it tells the probability for a particular class. But I am only getting 0 & 1.

I have put large k values also but to no gain. Though I have only 1000 samples with features around 200 and the matrix is largely sparse.

Can anybody tell me what could be the solution here?

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=**k**)`

The reason why you're getting only 0 & 1 is because of the n_neighbors = k parameter. If k value is set to 1, then you will get 0 or 1. If it's set to 2, you will get 0, 0.5 or 1. And if it's set to 3, then the probability outputs will be 0, 0.333, 0.666, or 1.

Also note that probability values are essentially meaningless in KNN. The algorithm is based on similarity and distance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be lack of variety of data in training and test sets.

If the features of a sample may only exist in a particular class and its features don't exist in any sample of other classes in training set, then that sample will be predicted to belong that class with probability of 100% (1) and 0% (0) for other classes. 
Otherwise; let say you have 2 classes and test a sample like `knn.predict_proba(sample)` and expect some result like `[[0.47, 0.53]]` The result will yield 1 in total in either way.

If thats the case, try generating your own test sample that has features from more than one classes objects in training set.

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for a possibe solution to a similar issue, and posting a snippet in case this helps others.

I used `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=21, weights='distance').fit(x, y)`. However, predict() yielded {0., 1.} as the only outputs, while n_neighbors + 1 outputs are possible. Setting the weights to `uniform` made predict() yield 22 unique outcomes as expected.