# Measuring prediction confidence for kNN multiclass classifier model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I am trying to work out the best way to quantify a single prediction's likelihood of being correct for a kNN model, but I am stumped on how to do this.

I understand that sklearn allows for the predict_proba method on kNN, but I do not entirely understand how this works for kNN.

Given that kNN uses similarity and distance to determine which class to place a sample in, is there any way to use these metrics to calculate a prediction confidence. For example, using the distance to the middle-point of the closest class and comparing with the distances to the next two class middle-points.

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: predict_proba is the number of neighbors, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158459/7949283.
You can use a calibration model to get meaningful probabilities : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html

Comment: @madaray thanks for sharing. Would you suggest using CalibratedClassifierCV then using predict_proba for all classes? Once calibrated, is the assumption that the probabilities would be indicative of the model confidence in each class for a given sample?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Be careful, the calibration layer is a model in itself, you have to look at its performance (brier score, calibration curve, decision threshold ...). In my experience, with enough data, it works well.